# splitting an interval symmetrically

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider an open ball centered at zero in ${R}^n$. If the real line is continuous, why is it not possible to cut it symmetrically in half (that is, without one boundary open and the other one closed?

Macroscopically I can do this (with an apple, say) and if there is no 'granularity' I don't understand where it goes wrong.

I have asked this question to a professor (in an admittedly too advanced class) who just said something about the mean value theorem, which I can't seem to fit into the context.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that "cut it in half" means find non-empty $A$ and $B$ so $A\cup B=\Bbb R$ and $x<y$ for every $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Note that you *can* cut $\Bbb Q$ into two disjoint open intervals this way, but the *completeness* of $\Bbb R$ makes it impossible for $\Bbb R$. The set $B$ is bounded below (by any element of $A$) so it has greatest lower bound $\alpha$. Now either $\alpha\in A$, in which case $A=(-\infty,\alpha]$ and $B=(\alpha,\infty)$, or $\alpha\in B$...

Comment: ...just like A is bounded above by $\beta$. Why can't $\alpha \in \_italic_{B}$ and  $\beta \in \_italic_A$ (or the other way round)?

Comment: @bolzep The least upper bound of $A$ is equal to the greatest lower bound of $B$.

Comment: It still contradicts my intuition that there is supposed to not be for both a last included and first not-included element; how to write them down is another question

Comment: Well, evidently your intuition is simply wrong.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha$ is the largest element of $A$ and $\beta$ is the smallest element of $B$. By our definition of "cut in half" above, $\alpha\in A$ and $\beta\in B$ implies $\alpha<\beta$. So there exists $x$ with $\alpha<x<\beta$; hence $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$, contradicting $A\cup B=\Bbb R$.

Comment: (replying to another comment, deleted:) There is no "next" number! Think about this. What's the smallest strictly positive number? No such thing, obviously. Which is just a more precise way of saying there is no "next number" after $0$.

Comment: I couldn't write the "next" number down, but this need not mean it doesn't consist... the real line is made out of totally ordered numbers, so I can't see why there wouldn't be some 'infinitesimal' first positive number (same goes for the possibility of $\beta$ to directly follow $\alpha$) (Sorry for the instant deletion, wanted to think about your second comment first)

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense to me as written; I'm going to assume you meant "I couldn't write the "next" number down, but this need not mean it doesn't exist..." What's your point? I didn't say that the fact that you can't write it down shows that it doesn't exist! I _proved_ that it doesn't exist!

Comment: And btw, come to think of it, infinitesimals have roughly nothing to do with the non-existence of the next number after zero. Because if $i>0$ it cannot be the next number after zero, because $0<i/2<i$.

Comment: As defined in Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal), infinitesimals are "closer to zero than any standard real number, but [...] not zero". Would it be possible to define their supremum as the smallest postive real number?

Comment: the infinitesimals don't have a supremum

Comment: There are a million ways you could find to try to justify the existence of a smallest positive real. **Whatever** one you come up with next, **note** that it has to somehow survive the following: There is no smallest positive real. Proof: If $r$ is a positive real it's not the smallest, because $r/2$ is even smaller. qed. Don't ask about your next plan unless you can explain how it's immune to that argument.

Comment: The only thing I could come up with is lim x^n, ||x|| < 1, but that's already zero. I have not been taught about hyperreals, so I guess I have to accept the nonexistance of suprema.

Comment: you don't have to "accept" much. If the infinitesimals had a sup that _would_ be the smallest positive real, but there (obviously) is no smallest positive real.

Answer (score 0):

By a "cut in half" I will mean a "cut" $(A,B)$ of $\Bbb R$, as I defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4089961/4280). It's similar to what David Ullrich defined in his answer, inspired on Dedekind cuts.

The space $\Bbb R$ is connected (which is related to the intermediate value theorem holding, which is also a consequence of that connectedness), and both of which follow (partly) from the fact that all bounded sets have a supremum (which you could very well call a defining characteristic of $\Bbb R$), in the terminology of the quoted post, $\Bbb R$ has no gaps or jumps, so all cuts have the property that $\max A$ exists **or** $\min B$ exists, so there is no "symmetric" cut.