# Do elements of (strictly) totally ordered sets have unique neighbours?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, order-theory

The real numbers form a totally ordered set, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order) is also strictly totally ordered, i.e.

- transitive: $a < b, b < c \Rightarrow a < c$
- semiconnex: if $a \neq b$ then $a < b$ or $b < a$
- antireflexive: $a < a$ is false
- asymmetric: if $a < b$ is true then $b < a$ is false

Following a discussion under the answer to [my last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089321/splitting-an-interval-symmetrically/4089330?noredirect=1#comment8451160_4089330) if in a strictly totally ordered set such as $\mathbb{R}$, every element $x$ has a unique neighbor: the element which is larger (smaller) than $x$, and smaller (larger) than every other element $c$ such that $c > x$ ($c < x$).

Since these relationships can be determined for all $ x ∈\mathbb{R}$, I suspect the problem lies in having to determine an infinite number of relations.

If this was true, then a smallest positive real number would exist.

Comment: The real line is a dense ordering, which means no element, such as $0$, has an immediate successor nor an immediate predecessor (I'm guessing that's what you mean by unique neighbors).

Answer (score 1):

No, in e.g. $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$ no element has "unique neighbours": for $0$ e.g. if $x>0$ there is always $x'$ so that $0 < x' < x$. The order is a so-called *dense order*.

Answer (score 0):

What would you want the successor to $0$ be?

Do you want to say the successor of $0$ is $1$? If so, I can disprove that by showing you $1/2$.

Do you want to say the successor of $0$ is $.001$? If so, I can disprove that by showing you $.0005$.

Do you want to be sneaky and write down a number on a hidden piece of paper, and not tell me what it is, but instead just tell me "I've just written down a number $x > 0$ which is the successor to $0$ !!!", I can still disprove it by showing you the mathematical expression $\frac{x}{2}$. You can easily prove the following implication:
$$0 < x \quad\implies\quad 0 < \frac{x}{2} < x
$$
It follows that $x$ is not the successor to $0$, no matter what value you assign to it.

The conclusion is that $0$ has no successor in the real line.

---

Let me add that the Wikipedia axioms of a total order are fine for a general definition of a total order, but the specific total order on the real line $\mathbb R$ satisfies some additional axioms not on that list, namely:

- **Trichotomy**: For every $x \in \mathbb R$, exactly one of the following holds: $x = 0$; or $x > 0$; or $-x > 0$.
- **Closure of positive numbers under addition**: For every $x,y \in \mathbb R$, if $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ then $x+y > 0$
- **Closure of positive numbers under multiplication**: For every $x,y \in \mathbb R$, if $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ then $xy > 0$.

You'll find these additional axioms [here on wikipedia](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ehart/m524/realprop.pdf), for example. You can see at the same link that there is another very important inequality axiom called the completeness axiom, but the above three inequality axioms are already enough to prove the implication I wrote earlier, from which one concludes that $0$ has no successor in the real line.

If you want to work with a total order that does *not* satisfy these additional inequality axioms, then the order you are working with is not the order on the real numbers.

Comment: Ignoring consequences like contradiction with the intermediate value theorem, why can't there be a supremum of the infinitesimal numbers ("smaller than any real") to fill out that role?
If there is no specific number next to any real number, what is there? In any discrete 1D example I can think of (string of atoms etc), every element has two neighbours, whether they can be named or not

Comment: "If there is no specific number next to any real number, what is there?" There are: lots and lots and lots and lots of real numbers, packed densely into the real number line. Yes, any discrete 1D example you can think of has those properties. The real number line is not discrete.

Comment: When you start talking about models for the real number axioms that allow infinitesmals, things only get worse: you don't lose any of the old, densely packed real numbers, there's  just ever more of things packed in there.

Comment: Among these densely packed numbers on each side, isn't there always one that is largest/smallest? Since they can all be compared...

Comment: That question is already answered in my post. So, all I can suggest at this point is two things. First, try to understand the axiomatic structure of the real numbers, and in particular try to prove the implication that I wrote down "if $0 < x$ then $0 < \frac{x}{2} < x$", directly from the axioms for the real numbers. Next, try to understand how to use that implication to prove that $0$ has no successor. Whether you wish to work with these axioms in your own mathematical investigations is a different issue, but understanding of their logical consequences is essential for a mathematician.

Comment: I was thinking about taking the supremum among the reals, which by definition would be the smallest; I thought the 'dx' in integrals can be considered as infinitesimal, so I thought one might not even need new models; but one would probably need to know more than Wikipedia about hyperreals to understand how "things get worse"